# How to stack li's vertical on mobile but keep horizontal on desktop

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an unordered list which uses `display:inline-block;` to keep it horizontal however I want it to display vertical on mobile.

This is the code I currently have for the unordered list:

```
<ul style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin:auto;">
    <li style="display: inline-block; border: 5px solid black; padding: 10px;background-color:red;"><a style="color: white;" href="register">Register</a></li>
    <li style="display: inline-block; border: 5px solid black; padding: 10px;background-color:green;"><a style="color: white;" href="shop">Find Your Photos!</a></li>
    <li style="display: inline-block; border: 5px solid black; padding: 10px;background-color:purple;"><a style="color: white;" href="about">Meet The Team</a></li>
</ul>
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use @media-queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
          li{
             display:block;
          }
    }
```

You have to try what width will be good

Answer (score 1):

As for me, inline styles are not a good way but in your case use media query and set `display: block` for your list items inside it.

*Note: you need to use `important` otherwise inline styles will take precedence and you won't see any result .*

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ul li {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin:auto;">
  <li style="display: inline-block; border: 5px solid black; padding: 10px;background-color:red;"><a style="color: white;" href="register">Register</a></li>
  <li style="display: inline-block; border: 5px solid black; padding: 10px;background-color:green;"><a style="color: white;" href="shop">Find Your Photos!</a></li>
  <li style="display: inline-block; border: 5px solid black; padding: 10px;background-color:purple;"><a style="color: white;" href="about">Meet The Team</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You don't need to use inline styles or `important` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use media Query

```css
ul{
  margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin:auto;
  }
ul li{
  display: inline-block; border: 5px solid black; padding: 10px;background-color:red;
  }
ul li:nth-child(2){
  background-color:green;
}
ul li:nth-child(3){
  background-color:purple;
}
ul li a{color:#fff;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   ul li{
     display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop">Find Your Photos!</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">Meet The Team</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media query and make the li as display: block.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){ ul li{ display: block; margin: 20px 0;}}
```

Notice the top & bottom margin for li. It is to separate the lists.
(Assumed that 768px is the breakpoint you want.)